# Postscript font names and windows font names in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, fonts, itext

I am using **ItextSharp** to extract font of PDF documents. While using **PostscriptFontName** method I'm able to get the font names like **NJNSWD+Papyrus-Regular**. Is there are way to convert this name to windows font name e.g. it Times New Roman, Arial etc.? Or other ways to get the font names in like "Times new Roman" etc.

Comment: When an ISO standard uses the verb "shall", you know that what follows is *normative* language. Your question is about removing prefixes such as "NJNSWD+", but if you would do that, your PDF would cease to be a PDF, because it would break one of the normative rules of the standard.

Comment: Also: (1.) Many fonts allow embedding, but do not legally allow extraction from a document. You may be trying to do that is illegal. (2.) When a font name starts with a prefix as described in the standard, only a subset of the font can be extracted. You say you extract a font from a PDF, but if the PDF only contains a subset of the font, you can never extract the full font. (3.) Maybe you meant to say that you want to extract the font *information*, but you said you want to extract the font instead...